# When may storage JSON API return HTTP redirect?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Under which conditions (if any) will the JSON storage API return a 303 or 307 status code?

The [error code reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes) mentions that this may happen, but for these status gives no further details on when this might happen.

In particular, may this happen in response to an [object operation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#methods)?

Background: I'd like to avoid implementing support for redirects in my client if this not needed (to avoid the extra complexity).

Comment: You're writing your own HTTP client?!

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to an HTTPS endpoint, the cloud management system may decided that it wants you to instead connect to a different endpoint. This can be for many different reasons such as load balancing, resource has been moved, the resource is not available via the endpoint requested, etc.

I wrote a C++ SDK for Google, AWS and Azure. Receiving redirects is very common, so make sure that your code handles this correctly.

> In particular, may this happen in response to an object operation?

You need to handle redirects for all HTTP operations. It does not matter which API you are calling. For correctly written code, you don't care what the API is, you follow the redirect.

Comment: Would you have an example of a redirect received from Google Cloud? How do you decide whether to apply the redirect to all subsequent requests, just the one for which you got the redirect, or just a subset (e.g. for the same bucket, user, region...).

Comment: I would study one of Google's SDKs as they publish the source code. For the most part Google APIs are complete units meaning that you use the same published endpoint for each API call. You only use a different endpoint if you are redirected. Do not apply intelligence to the redirection and try to guess that the next API call should also be redirected.